# Ubuntu Server 21.04, GNOME Desktop in VMware: Terminal Font Problem

Tags: server, gnome, fonts, virtualization, desktop-environments

I have installed Ubuntu Server 21.04 and GNOME desktop in a VMware Player virtual machine (VM) on a Windows 10 host. The desktop seems normal otherwise, but in Terminal I have a weird font:

[image]

Previously, I tried Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. It had the same font problem, and was also more generally dysfunctional. Among other things, the desktop was barely responsive, and responses to commands in Terminal did not display until I switched away (via e.g., Alt-Tab) and then back.

Terminal itself does not appear to be the problem: I had the same result when using Tilix instead. Adjusting VM resolution or 3D graphics does not seem to have any effect.

I did not have this problem when I started over, this time installing the Lubuntu desktop in Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. I have also not had this problem with a standard Ubuntu 21.04 desktop installation in VMware Player.

The command I used to install GNOME desktop was as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

I would guess that `--no-install-recommends` is the culprit, but I used that with the Lubuntu installation as well. Without that modification, the GNOME desktop installation command adds a great deal of unwanted software, defeating the purpose of installing Server.

I would ideally focus my troubleshooting on the typeface if possible. Then again, this new installation is largely unused; there may be other problems lurking somewhere. I fear that is the case, since the typeface problem was originally accompanied by that dysfunctionality in Server 20.04.

Comment: What does the command `fc-match monospace` output?

Comment: That command produces DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"

This question motivates me to add a closing sentence or two to my question.

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah, TBH I would have expected something else and planned to suggest that you install the `fonts-dejavu-core` package. But it's already there.

Comment: `sudo apt install gnome-session gdm3` provides even more minimal install with working fonts.